# How can i put an if else inside cshtml using Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core, razor

I have a list that gets populated with fruits.

```
<select ng-options=" (s.fruit != null ? ', ' + s.fruit : '') for s in fruitList"></select>
```

s.fruit is either 'A' (Apple) , 'O' (Orange) , 'B' (Banana)

The output in the dropdownlist will be the id + A for example.
So will get:

```
     1, A
     2, O
     3, O
     4, B
     5, A
```

I want to output:

```
    1, Apple
    2, Orange
    3, Orange
    4, Banana
    5, Apple
```

Can i do something like

```
    <select ng-options=" (s.fruit != null ? ', ' + GetfruitName(s.fruit) : '') for s in fruitList"> 
    </select>
```

and define the function in the controller ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,you can define a function in controller like the demo:

Code:

```
 <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select ng-options="(s.fruit != null ? s.id+', ' + GetfruitName(s.fruit) : '') for s in fruitList" ng-model=""></select>
</div>

@section scripts{
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {

            $scope.fruitList = [
                {
                    id: "1",
                    fruit: "A"
                },
                {
                    id: "2",
                    fruit: "O"
                },
                {
                    id: "3",
                    fruit: "O"
                },
                {
                    id: "4",
                    fruit: "B"
                },
                {
                    id: "5",
                    fruit: "A"
                }
            ];
            $scope.GetfruitName = function (fruit) {
                switch (fruit) {
                    case "A":
                        return "Apple";
                    case "B":
                        return "Banana";
                    case "O":
                        return "Orange";
                    default: return fruit;  
                };
            }
        });
        
    </script>
}
```

result:

[image]